# regex - sed - cambiar nombre de filas

Tags: regex, sed

Estoy planteando un regex para intentar hacer un cambio de la inicial, por el nombre completo según el data set del Titanic.

Estos son los nombres a modo de ejemplo:

```
name,"gender","age","class","embarked","country","ticketno","fare","sibsp","parch","survived"
Abbing, Mr. Anthony,"male",42,"3rd","S","United States",5547,7.11,"0","0","no"
Abbott, Mr. Eugene Joseph,"male",13,"3rd","S","United States",2673,20.05,"0","2","no"
Abbott, Mr. Rossmore Edward,"male",16,"3rd","S","United States",2673,20.05,"1","1","no"
Abbott, Mrs. Rhoda Mary 'Rosa',"female",39,"3rd","S","England",2673,20.05,"1","1","yes"
Abelseth, Miss. Karen Marie,"female",16,"3rd","S","Norway",348125,7.13,"0","0","yes"
Abelseth, Mr. Olaus JÃ¸rgensen,"male",25,"3rd","S","United States",348122,7.13,"0","0","yes"
Abelson, Mr. Samuel,"male",30,"2nd","C","France",3381,24,"1","0","no"
Abelson, Mrs. Hannah,"female",28,"2nd","C","France",3381,24,"1","0","yes"
Abi-Al-MunÃ , Mr. Nasif Qasim,"male",27,"3rd","C","Lebanon",2699,18.1509,"0","0","yes"
```

El cambio que quiero hacer es según estos valores:

- C: Cherbourg
- S: Southampton
- Q: Queenstown

Inicialmente lo he planteado así, pero no hace el cambio:

```
sed -e 's/,C,/,Cherbourg,/g' -e 's/,Q,/,Queenstown,/g' -e 's/,S,/,Southhampton,/g' titanic.csv
```

Quiero hacerlo mediante `sed` y estoy pensando hacerlo con `regex`, pero no consigo acceder hasta el campo donde se indica la variable que quiero cambiar:

```
[a-zA-Z,.]*,[Mr|Mrs].[a-zA-Z]*,"[male|female]",[0-9][0-9],[1st|2nd|3rd|crew],C...
```

Alguien me puede explicar qué hago mal en una opción o la otra, por favor?
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué con Sed? Con Awk sería muy rápido y menos doloro :) Por cierto, parece que falta una columna de datos, pues la 2.ª dice "gender" y allí sale el nombre. ¿Será que el primer campo es el apellido y el segundo el nombre?

Comment: A todo esto, tu código está bien, el problema es que buscas `,C,`, cuando el contenido es `,"C",`. Es decir, debes poner comillas alrededor de cada letra.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', con awk también me sirve, no tengo ningún problema. Simplemente entiendo mejor sed que awk, pero si me propones con awk, genial. Sí que quiero usar un regex para hacer el cambio y pensaba que con awk no lo usaría.

Comment: eso es cierto, con Awk solamente comprobarías igualdades, con algo así como `if ($5 == "C") $5 = "bla"`

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', mi código no sé si está bien o no (dices que sí), pero probándolo con el script veo que no cumplo las condiciones. Creo que una vez llegado a "C", tampoco sé hacer el cambio por "Cherbourg" pero haré la prueba

Comment: `sed 's/,"C",/"Cherbourg"/'` funciona perfectamente

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', con awk podría añadir condiciones en líneas diferentes? es decir, además de añadir esta para cambiar el valor de esa columna, debería hacer otra línea de awk para otras condiciones que quiera añadir?